# Is coordinate chart what gives rise to coordinates on a Manifold?

Tags: general-topology

Basically, given a manifold M, I have a chart mapping $U \to U' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, can I interpret every point in $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n) \in U'$ as the "coordinates" of a point on the manifold M? And different coordinate charts correspond to different choices of coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first pass, sure---a chart can be thought of as defining **a possible choice of** (local) coordinates on a manifold. In fact, charts are sometimes referred to as "coordinate charts" for basically this very reason.

The sticking point is referring to **"the"** coordinates---there may be a canonical or convenient coordinate system for a portion of a manifold (= a chart), but there are infinitely many different possible coordinate systems--even locally--on a manifold (= charts). Properly, handing someone a manifold means that you have given them **all** possible charts that play nicely together (= transition functions). In practice, we often pass around manifolds by means of a small handful of charts that cover the entire manifold, with it being inferred that we should be considering the maximal collection of charts generated by this small collection that are interoperable (the *maximal atlas*).